# How to get two table value using Linq

Tags: c#, sql

I have two table one is Administrator table and another is Teacher table .
I want to display these both tables values in single Gridview .
I have make id as a primary key in Administrator table and make this tech_id as foreign key in Teacher table .
Now how to get these table values together in single gridview as shown in pic [image]

Now please any body help me how to get these two value together using Linq . 
I have try but  I can't make any more

```
   private void loadgri()
    {
        StudentDatabaseEntities empl = new StudentDatabaseEntities();

      var query=from g in empl.Teachers
                join m in empl.Administrators on g.id equals m.id
                where m.username=="cs"
                select new{
   Name = g.username,


        };
       }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  In what way is this not working?  Do these tables really share `id` values like that?

Comment: You said that the `Administrator.ID = Teacher.tech_id`. So you are joining on the wrong keys in the Linq.

Comment: Your entities have navigation properties you can use instead of joining https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a `join` if you have already a [navigation-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
var query= from t in empl.Teachers
           where t.Administrator.username == "cs"
           select new { Teacher = t.username, Administrator = t.Administrator.username };
```

This is just an example, but you see that you can access all properties of both entities.

[Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that he may need to add an `Include` instruction, like this: `from t in empl.Teachers.Include(teacher => teacher.Administrator) where ...`

Comment: @TaoGómezGil: well, that depends on what LINQ provider he uses at all(he didn't mention entity framework). But even with `Linq2Entities` it depends on how you want to retrieve data. Entity framework allows eager- or lazy-loading. If you use `Include` you would use eager loading. That means the generated sql will include all joins even if you don't use any property of the related tables. If you don't use `Include` you'd use lazy-loading, then those properties are loaded when you access them(but probably using multiple querie).

Answer (score 3):

To show all the teachers and their administrator, you don't have to use "join", you could just use the navigation property:

```
var query = from g in empl.Teachers
            where g.Administrator.username=="cs"
            select new {
                Teacher_Id = g.Id,
                Teacher_Name = g.username,
                Administrator_Id = g.Id,
                Administrator_Name = g.Administrator.username,
                //etc...
            };
```

Comment: it through exception :The relationship 'StudentDatabaseModel.FK_Table_Teacher' was not loaded because the type 'StudentDatabaseModel.Teacher' is not available.

Comment: I am not sure the root cause of the exception, have you tried refreshing the model in the designer?